# Installing Mavericks via Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I have the Install OS X Mavericks.app in Recovery Mode and I want to execute it somehow to start the installation from the terminal, so I don't need the internet connection.

I executed the InstallAssistantTool within Contents/Resources, but that just leaves a blank line and the terminal doesn't do anything.

I also tried createinstallmedia to create a bootable SD card, but that tells me that the .app file isn't a valid OS Installer.

How can I finally install Mavericks from Recovery Mode, within the terminal?

** EDIT: **
I want to install Mavericks from the Install OS X Mavericks.app and when I go to /Contents/MacOS I want to execute InstallAssistent, but the problem is that the installer hangs on checking eligibility with Apple, while my Internet connection works.

The problem is, that my SSD is empty/erased and thus I have no access to the App Store and so on, as it is my only Apple device.

Comment: When it hangs on checking eligibility, what does the log say (⌘L)?

Comment: I do have the Mavericks Installer on my Recovery Partition, the problem is though, that it hangs on checking eligibility.

Now, I want to install the Mavericks without Internet Connection, but that doesn't seem to work?

Comment: I can't open the Log, because my Mac stops responding. And I backed up the Recovery Partition

Comment: Could I also use createinstallmedia to my SD Card to boot from the SD Card? The only problem with that is, that the Terminal error says that the OS X installer isn't a valid OS installer

Comment: OK, where is yours Mavericks file, a 5.5 Gig (the installer) without it you can not do anything.

Comment: I suppose I don't have that file, then? I do have a .dmg file with the installer in it, I think, can I use that? It's on Windows, though?

Comment: Now we are making progress...:) yes..

Comment: How could I do that then? I am not quite sure how to go about this..

Comment: I tried to give you instructions in my answer but got 2 negative votes, so lets hope that one of them knows the right answer.

Comment: I did see it, so do I just put the .dmg on the SD card, copy it to an HFS partition and execute it? Or?

Comment: sorry, let see if one of the negative voters knows a good answer! (but a hint, the SD card has to be at least 8 Gig, and it has to be formatted to OSX needs.

Comment: Can I put the Mavericks.dmg on my SD Card, read it in Terminal, copy the .dmg to an HFS partition and then use that to createinstallmedia?

Comment: Okay, I am almost ready, but my Terminal says: "/Volumes/Untitled is not a valid volume mount point." while I just formatted the SD Card and I am pretty sure it is Untitled, as I used Tab completion from the Terminal

Comment: you are doing well so far, you will figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Possibly I am missing something here, but unless you have a very slow internet connection or none at all, recovery mode should be able to install the O/S version that shipped with the computer. The recovery partition downloads and installs the O/S for you, no terminal needed. Unless you **want** to do it that way as an exercise in technical exploration, this method was developed to eliminate shipping recovery media with every Mac and make the process as easy as possible.

Once that O/S version is on your Mac you can then upgrade/update to the latest version of Mavericks

Comment: I wish it were that easy. For some reason, the download speed for that operating system is incredibly slow. (I was using my university internet with Gigabit speeds)

Answer (score 1):

To execute inside the `Install OS X Mavericks.app/Contents/MacOS` folder use `"./Install OS X Mavericks"` (with quotes because has spaces in it) but it looks like the installer thinks it's reinstall that will not read the installation files in the drive. It will simply redownload the components required (5GB again)

The SD Card/Flash Drive/'whatever that you plug in it' is already mounted in Recovery mode. To get there try `cd -P /Volumes` then do `ls`. You should then see your drive name.
Do `cd <drive_name>` and you will then in your SD Card/Flash Drive root.

Inside the .dmg file I found `Install OS X Mavericks.app/System/Installation/CDIS/OS X Installer.app`. I haven't test it yet because I'm fixing my friend's Mac when I'm at his house which I'm not now. You can try executing that (`Contents/MacOS/OS X Installer`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this find the **InstallESD.dmg** inside the **Install OS X Mavericks.app** should be in the **SharedSupport** dir and mount it, then find the **BaseSystem.dmg** inside the mounted **OS X InstallESD** and mount that.
then run the cmd `sudo /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/System/Installation/CDIS/OS\ X\ Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/OS\ X\ Installer /Volumes/OS\ X\ Install\ ESD/Packages/OSInstall.mpkg` you might have to prefix the volume you want to install onto at the end of the command cant quit remember but I have used this cmd before to install OS X from the terminal.